# Creating only one object, still Destructor is called 2 times . Why?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class A {

 public :
     ~A(){
    cout << " A is destroyed " << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{

 public :
     ~B(){
         cout << " B is destroyed " << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    B obj;
    B * p = &obj;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

In the main function I am creating **only one** object of class B, which inherits class A.
When I am deleting that object using the pointer , destructor is called and prints message But then , I am not able to understand that why destructor is called **twice** ?

Comment: You should post the output of the program.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: That would be meaningless in this case. Besides, how do you post those nasal demons?

Comment: @BiagioFesta ...     I am sorry , but I am not able to paste my output here . I am new user , and don't know how to do it . sorry :|

Comment: You probably should define a [virtual destructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/10077) in `A` as well, although I don't believe that has anything to do with your immediate problem.

Comment: This is ill-formed code: it's a very bad idea to try to `delete` a pointer pointing to a local variable.

Comment: side note : dont include std bitsc++

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour, that's why.

Comment: @MSalters Just my local time, I'm very tired and I didn't look properly the code. Sorry, I'd edited just two second after the *enter* of the comment :)

Comment: @GillBates: I think that header is deliberately provided by GCC as a convenience extension to get the entire standard library. It's not portable, but it's certainly working as intended.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read [**How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**]  At least leave us with a **[MCVE]** that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Comment: Don't `delete` it if you didn't `new` it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you have a variable on the stack, so the destructor is automatically called at the end of the scope.

```
B obj; // <- Constructor called.
B * p = &obj;
delete p; // <- Bad, undefined behaviour, but destructor called. 
return 0; // <- Destructor called as `obj` goes out of scope.
```

You have caused *undefined behaviour* with this line:

```
delete p;
```

Remember that you should only ever delete memory that you have explicitly created (ie. with `new`).

Comment: Do you mean that when I am deleting an object with "delete" keyword, it still has space in memory ?

Comment: @NeerPatel No i mean that doing that causes undefined behavior. You should never `delete` what you didn't `new`.

Comment: okay . Got it. I have almost understood what you are trying say. But still want your opinion. Does that mean , all the objects that are allocated in **Heap** section(dynamically allocated) can be removed using "delete" keyword . But objects that are stored in **stack** section will not be removed by using "delete" keyword ?

Comment: @NeerPatel Objects initialized by using the `new` keyword can be destroyed using the `delete` keyword, this includes placement new's etc. trying to remove something that was not `new`ed with the `delete` keyword will cause undefined behavior, it might crash (segfault), it might work, it might even steal your car. *Undefined behavior* is undefined ....

Comment: very helpful . Thank You

Comment: @NeerPatel No problem, remember to mark as correct if this answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

First time destructor is called when line `delete p;` is executed. Second time - when `B obj;` goes out of scope of your `main`

Answer (score 3):

If you create an object in the stack like you did in this case you should not call delete on it.
the object will be automatically destroyed at the end of the scope (the enclosing}).
To answer you question calling delete resulted in calling the destructor twice